# On Bootstrap TAB click, init() function is calling everytime in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to implement dynamic tabs like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dynamic&stacked=h) on `abc.html`. I'm using SPA using angularJS and HTML5 and Bootstrap with (`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');`) to remove # .

I've `abcController.js`, Which contains `init` function like below.

```
(function init() {
        getUser();
})();

function getUser() {
        // Code
};
```

**Problem**: When i click on any tab, the `init()` function is calling.how to prevent this?  my url looks like this `http:localhost:1234/user`, on mouseover of `X` tab it shows `http:localhost:1234/user#X`

Comment: you need to remove `href="#"` from your tab anchor..I think changing in route does load controller and template again..

Comment: i tried with href="X" (instead #X). on mouse over X tab.. it is showing http:localhost:1234/X and on click going to home page. :)